# QTP question on the identification of image

Tags: repository, qtp

I have this image is a childitem in a cell of webtable, like Brower -> Page -> Webtable -> Link -> Image. After added this image in the repository, I try to add "file name" too in the description properties. Then when highlight it, turn out that it cannot be found on the page. I just could not understand why. Could someone please explan this to me?

Many thanks in advance

Allen

Comment: Did it highlight correctly before adding the *file name* property?

Comment: Is the filename changing dynamically? Try using the spy, and compare what you see from the spy with what you entered in the repository. You could also try using the update feature of the repo and see what changes. Without more details, we cannot offer much help.

Comment: @Motti, yes, it highlighted correctly.

Comment: @Tom E, The filename doesn't change. But there are several cells in the table contain the same image, only their indexes are different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you had an ordinal selector which is bigger than the set of objects that match the new description.

e.g. Say the description was `html tag:=img, alt:=""` this matched 10 links and your link was #6 so the ordinal identifier would be **6**. Now you added the filename and it matches only 2 objects. When QTP tries to identify the object it will see there are multiple matches and try to use the ordinal. But the ordinal is bigger than the number of elements matched so the object can not be identified.
You must either:

1. Make your description unique (so the ordinal will not be used) or
2. Update the ordinal in the description

I hope I guessed you problem correctly.